# How do I connect MYSQL workbench to my local Server?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have tried the following parameters below but it keeps saying that it can't connect to the MySQL Server:

The following parameters that were used to connect to the local server (not a remote server). Not only have I tried to connect to the server, but I also went into windows Services to stop the server and then restarted the server, but it still didn't properly connect to the server. What should I do?
hostname: localhost
port: 3306
username: root 
password: sesame

Comment: read here  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-getting-started-tutorial-create-connection.html

Comment: I am still having problems connecting to the server when I click on the new connection because I have to put in the right parameters before I can continue with the configure server management wizard.